# Android 13 - I got a permission error report. (FileNotFoundException(open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))

Tags: android, permissions, filenotfoundexception

> com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException
Failed to load resource There were 3 root causes: java.io.FileNotFoundException(/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/efda21e4-2721-2281-4519-163e567de326.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)) 
java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)) 
java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)) 
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

Hi, I received FileNotFoundException with Permission Denied Error from Firebase Crashlytics.

I know, before to publish, developer must set Granular media permissions for Android SDK33.
(https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)

Then, I declare uses-permission READ_MEDIA_IMAGES in manifest.xml, and request READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission in runtime.

I ran an internal test, the permission request came through normally and the picture showing well.

But after app distribution, I got a permission error report from few people.

As a result of communicating with people, it is said that all permissions(include READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) were allowed. However, it still says the photos are not showing up. The only solution is to proceed with reinstalling the app.

And also, refers to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions,
It is said that who has granted the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the past can automatically acquire all of the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, and READ_MEDIA_AUDIO permissions. I also confirmed this through internal test.

> If your app was previously granted the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, then any requested READ_MEDIA_* permissions are granted automatically when upgrading. You can use the following ADB command to review upgraded permissions:

I would love to get some advice from people who have the same problem as me.